# Load images seamlessly from internal storage in unity android?

Tags: c#, android, performance, unity-game-engine

I have been working on a puzzle game for the android device using Unity Game Engine, and I have been facing issues with loading the images from internal storage. The game has like 400-500 levels. Which are downloaded at runtime as per demand, and stored in the internal storage. The problem occurs in loading these images. Loading images from internal storage is very expensive. The function that is responsible for downloading or loading image is below,

```
public IEnumerator DownloadOrLoadImage(string link, string dirName, int index = -1)
{
    if (!loadFromResources)
    {
        //Extract Link
        int startPos = link.LastIndexOf("https://drive.google.com/file/d/") + "https://drive.google.com/file/d/".Length;
        int length = link.IndexOf("/view?usp=sharing") - startPos;
        if (length >= 1)
        {
            string ID = link.Substring(startPos, length);

            link = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + ID;

            if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/.cache/" + ID))
            {
                if (index != -1 && index == LevelMenuLoader.instance.totalJsonCount)
                {
                    LevelMenuLoader.instance.AfterMenuDownloadSequence();
                }
                print("Loading from the device");

                UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("file://" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/.cache/" + ID);
                yield return request.SendWebRequest();

                if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
                {
                    Debug.Log(request.error);
                }
                else
                {
                    byte[] bytes = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).data;

                    if (bytes.Length > 1)
                        this.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;
                }

                request.downloadHandler.Dispose();
                request.Dispose();
                isImageDownloaded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                LevelMenuLoader.instance.AfterMenuDownloadSequence();
                print("Downloading from the web");


                using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(link))
                {
                    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

                    if (request.isNetworkError || request.isHttpError)
                        Debug.Log(request.error);
                    else
                    {
                        this.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).texture;

                        byte[] bytes = ((DownloadHandlerTexture)request.downloadHandler).data;
                        if (bytes.Length > 1)
                        {
                            File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/.cache/" + ID, bytes);
                            isImageDownloaded = true;
                        }

                        request.downloadHandler.Dispose();
                        request.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //      Debug.Log("Loaded from resources");
        this.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = Resources.Load<Texture>("Levels/" + dirName + "/" + this.GetComponent<LevelInformation>().m_LevelID);
    }
```

I am sorry for it to be so long, but it's simply doing a check, if the file exists, load the image from storage or else download it. I found this to be the most efficient so far and with the least amount of lag. When it comes to loading 300+ images, it's seriously a headache and it takes up to 3-4 seconds to load the images, and in some devices, it won't load at all because of some memory usage limitations in some devices. It will really help if someone can help or guide me to optimize the code in a way that is very seamless and faster to load images.

PS: I have tried object pooling for scroll view, so I only load the images that are needed and dispose of them when they are not visible on the screen. But it's impractical as loading the image creates a bit of lag and it's not as fast as needed. Any suggestion will be great.

I am sorry if I am violating any guidelines or my formatting is not good. Please let me know so I can correct it.

Thank you.

Comment: You either have to sacrifice loading time or memory. Else, did you try creating smaller thumbnails (when downloading into device or from server, or creating on the fly though I suspect this is not viable since you already have loading time problem) for the screens where a lot of images are viewed instead?

Comment: Hi, @LukeVo Thanks for the reply. I don't mind the loading time, but loading 400+ images in the memory creates a lot of issues (it's not a lot of memory), but some devices have limitations of sudden memory usage spike, which prevent the game from loading images. It is highly noticed in Samsung devices and IOS. The game won't move past loading because of this. The thumbnails are pretty small in 512x512 around 100kb each. This is the smallest I can go for the thumbnail I guess. These images loading issues is only for the menu where these 400+ images are needed in the scroll view.

Comment: I used to develop games, not sure if it's different now but 100kB image file does not have the same footprint in memory. In memory it's always bitmap (i.e. 3 or 4 bytes per pixel). 512x512 is pretty big! I remember back then (10 years ago) we could only load about 2048x2048 texture and squeeze everything in that limit.

Comment: I understand. Is there any workaround for this? because going lower than 512x512 will result in very poor quality I suppose. We have optimized the images to the most to preserve quality with lower size.

Comment: Why do you need to load all 300 images? Users can't view them all at once. Say I assume you have a menu screen so user can pick a level, and a screen that actually need the big good image to play with. Menu screen, you load, say, 30 thumbnails of 50x50 for example, which would be very fast and use not a lot of memory. Then to the playing screen, you actually load the 512x512 files.

Comment: I have tried that approach. I created a custom scroll view that uses object pooling, and loads and unloads images as needed and visible on screen. it did not work because even loading one image drops the fps from 60 to something like 45 (which is quite noticeable while playing), doing that runtime is just a laggy mess. That is the reason why I had to go with loading all at once and storing in ram, so at least after loading, the experience is good. But, some devices just don't allow such sudden memory spike.

Comment: Are you doing that with thumbnails instead of the full resolution image? A 50x50 images on memory (assuming RGBA = 4 bytes per pixel) is just 10KB. Even if you load all 300 images it's just 3MB, barely anything on modern hardware (even acceptable for 10 years ago). I think the problem is something else. Can you do a performance check to see which code is slowing your app down? As for poll scrolling, I don't think you need it but even if you need it, we usually load the current screen and the 2 adjacent screens as well to provide better experience.

Comment: I have to research more about how unity works with memory. The normal ram usage is around a gigabyte with the game running. I have no clue why some devices like Samsung or apple would just deny ram usage. I am looking more into making it more efficient to load the images and store in ram.

Answer (score 0):

### maybe a solution

preload them at the beginning and then show them the player
This method is mainly used for computational games like Battlefield. For example, the particles and weapons are loaded at the beginning and when you need them they will not spawn with you but teleport to you for better performance. In your case, it should be a great solution to simply load all the images beforehand, that way it will run smoothly (as long as you haven't built in unreasonable debug logs or other unnecessary calculation processes)

Comment: Hi @somewhat32, thanks for the solution. That is what I do right now to avoid any loading later. And, it works like a charm for me on unity editor. But some mobile devices have some kind of limitation. They prevent apps and games from using ram in an instant. Especially in Samsung and IOS. That is strange behavior, on some devices the game works like a charm but loading takes so long, and in some, it just won't get past the loading screen. There is a game called Art puzzle on google play, which has the same mechanic as mine, but they do it flawlessly.

Comment: ah i see  you making a Art Puzzle game, and i thought you making your own gallery based on google drive. Anyway i think that they put the images into the game files, like they publish it with all the images at once. if you put the resolution down you could get away with about 300 levels youre at about 900 mb usage for the images, but you can recycle images if you get the chance. But even a gigabyte isnt much for a great game.
If you cant find any way to get arround the ram issue, i recommend to publish your game with all of these images implemented, no external sources.

Comment: An advantage is that the player dont have to be connected to the internet.

Comment: Hi, Yes we have pretty much the same concept, only difference being ours is a jigsaw game. They did not put all the images in the game files. Their download size is very concise around 50 megabytes or so. They do download them in real time as they themselves have about 500+ levels (that is around 1500+ images). The reason we went with the hassle of doing it real-time download is to save download size for players from the play store and they don't have to wait for the downloading to finish.

Comment: We have coded the game in a way that the players don't have to wait for anything to finish. We have vanilla 10 levels in the game, before they finish these 10 levels, other assets in order should be there. They can start playing instantly and the game will manage all the downloading in the background. The game can be played offline as well.

Comment: does "Art Puzzle" was made with Unity? i dont think there is a simple way to do it, its way harder then i thought you need some way to only read the images in the best way but even this is challanging, i recommend you to watch a few tutorials about game launcher made with unity, they showing you some ways how to download data directly from google drive through script. Good Luck at this point i cant help anymore this is way too complex for me

Comment: I understand. The art puzzle was made in Unity. Thank you so much for your suggestions. To explain how our system works,
We have the entire architecture laid out. We have a JSON file on the drive that is downloaded every time you are connected to the internet to get latest updates. The game goes through JSON to verify updates if any, and download directly from the drive and store it in the devices. Downloading is not the issue, but loading the files from the storage, which is an expensive process. The game works fine, but some devices do not allow so much loading IDK why? maybe a bug?

Comment: unfortunatly i dont even know how to get files saved in your local storage besides the PlayerPrefs, but this wouldnt help you out in this case. Maybe you need someone else who know this and have its own experience with this already, i really cant help you out here